# iOS xcode Alternative to UIWebview didFinishLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have a webview that when loaded, the user is logged in by a POST request. After they are logged in, I want them to be taken to a webpage. My POST request is a URL as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[_scoreWebView setDelegate:self];

NSMutableURLRequest *detailRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myrul"]];

[detailRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *sendInfo =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"action=login&EMAIL=email&PASSWORD=password", nil];

NSData *infoData = [sendInfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[detailRequest setHTTPBody:infoData];

[_scoreWebView loadRequest:detailRequest];
}
```

This log in process works fine. However, after I send the user to my webpage it is launching webviewdidfinishload infinitely. I know that it fires each time something is loaded. Is there an alternate solution to redirecting the user to my page after log in? Also, I have three different pages that the user could be redirected to based on their input, this is just one of them for simplicity. This is my finishload method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     //Check here if still webview is loding the content
if (webView.isLoading)
    return;
else //finished
    NSLog(@"finished loading");

NSLog(@"%@ in calendar", _thisScriptUniqueID);

NSString *fullURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl/%@#score", _thisScriptUniqueID];

NSLog(@"%@", fullURL);


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_scoreWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Is there a different method that could be used to take the user to the page, or would it be possible to include both in the viewDidLoad?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I decided that the functionality would work a lot better on the server side. I made it so that the same URL logs the user in and brings them to the desired page at the same time.